# how to split a dicom image into tiles?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, slice, dicom

I'm trying to use the image_slicer function to split a DICOM image into tiles, but it's not recognizing the DICOM.

I've already read the DICOM and converted them into np arrays:

dcm_files[0]

```
array([[-1024, -1024, -1024, ..., -1024, -1024, -1024],
       [-1024, -1024, -1024, ..., -1024, -1024, -1024],
       [-1024, -1024, -1024, ..., -1024, -1024, -1024],
       ...,
       [-1024, -1024, -1024, ..., -1024, -1024, -1024],
       [-1024, -1024, -1024, ..., -1024, -1024, -1024],
       [-1024, -1024, -1024, ..., -1024, -1024, -1024]], dtype=int16)
```

and am able to view the image through:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.fromarray(dcm_files[0])
img.show()
```

and then trying to slice it:

```
import image_slicer
image_slicer.slice(img, 64)
```

*Error: 'Image' object has no attribute 'read'*

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The module `image_slicer` uses filenames, not file instances. Therefore you have to save the array to some localisation. You can use [`tempfile` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) for that purpose.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import image_slicer
import tempfile

array = np.random.randint(0,200, size=(128,128), dtype='int32')

img = Image.fromarray(array)

temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
img.save(temp.name, format="png")

image_slicer.slice(temp.name, 4)
#if you want to play with the slices:
tiles = image_slicer.slice(temp.name, 4, save=False)
```